# Sum of Named Ranges to Array in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have values 1,2,3 and 2,3,4 in columes A and B respectively. I want column C to be 1+2, 2+3, 3+4. I have named the first 3 cells of column A as RANGE_A and the first 3 cells of column B as RANGE_B

I have tried sum(RANGE_A, RANGE_B), but that gives me the actual total of 15 in every cell of the output range.

I don't want to do this in VBA, and it would be cleaner if I can use the ranges like I have tried, but if all else fails i'll be just using A1+B1,A2+B2 etc..

*****   EDIT   ********************************
Where you want to sum two named ranges ={sum(RANGE_A, RANGE_B)} produces a scalar value, reflected in every cell of the output array, equal to the sum of both columns.

My solution is in fact, incredibly simple (thanks to **QHarr**, who got this right even when my original question was wrongly written!)

={RANGE_A + RANGE_B} produces an output array where each value is the sum of each pair of cells in each range. That's all i was looking for!

Cheers
J

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just use `=A1*B1` in C1, and fill down...?

Comment: Hi Olly, for presentation purposes. The users of the tool will benefit from seeing a named range which has a name they can relate to. A1*B1 requires investigation to understand what the cell's value means

Comment: Then why not use a listobject table - then the formula will use structured references - something like: `=[@[Data Item A]]*[@[Data Item B]]`

Comment: equally good solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to select C1:C3 and enter the following in the formula bar:

```
=RANGE_A*RANGE_B
```

then press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter as an array formula.

[image: data]

For addition you can use:

```
=RANGE_A+RANGE_B
```

Comment: QHarr, i made a right balls up of my post. It should have a +, not a *.

Comment: Simply change to a + :-)